# Is removing multiple elements from a set in the middle of a foreach safe?

Tags: java, foreach, set

Is the following code safe? Assume its single-threaded.

```
for(String s : set){
    set.remove(s);
    set.remove(randomElementFromSet());
}
```

I'm pretty sure this should be fine, but I want to double check that I run no risk of iterating over an element that has already been removed.

Also if possible please provide reference so I can look it up next time.

Comment: No its not. You can use failsafe iterators for the same. Refer the [link](http://www.journaldev.com/378/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-when-using-an-iterator) for more information

Comment: No, it probably throws ConcurrentModificationException. Use iterators as stated in last comment.

Comment: Why don't you test it? With a standard HashSet or TreeSet, you'll get a ConcurrentModificationException, as documented.

Comment: Did you create a test scenario and executed the code? That would've answered your question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it? You would get ConcurrentModificationException.

One safe way to remove elements from a Collection while iterating over it is by using an Iterator explicitly:

```
for(Iterator<String> iter = set.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    String s = iter.next();
    iter.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not filter a collection using a for-each loop as you can get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

To do it correctly you can use an `Iterator`, or `removeIf`. Both of these pieces of code print `[Foo]`.

Approach using `Iterator`:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz"));
for (Iterator<String> i = set.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
    if (i.next().contains("B"))
        i.remove();
System.out.println(set);
```

Approach using `removeIf` (Java 8):

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz"));
set.removeIf(str -> str.contains("B"));
System.out.println(set);
```